# Перенаправления на страницу по таймеру единожды для уникального пользователя

Tags: javascript, html, cookie

Как заставить этот скрипт срабатывать единожды для уникального пользователя?

Js:

```
setTimeout("location.href = ' http://ru.stackoverflow.com';",15000);
```

Comment: <script type="text/JavaScript">
<!--
setTimeout("location.href = ' http://ru.stackoverflow.com';",15000);
-->
</script>

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

В тело этой функции добавьте установку специальной куки. И перед запуском проверяйте есть эта кука у пользователя или нет, если нет - выполняйте скрипт.

Допустим имя куки будет cookieName

```
re = new RegExp('[; ]cookieName=([^\\s;]*)');
sMatch = (' '+document.cookie).match(re);
if (!sMatch)
{
    setTimeout("location.href = ' http://ru.stackoverflow.com';",15000);
}
```

Можно ещё сделать через базу данных на сервере, но это бесполезный overhead